# apply rate limit login api on IP specific not gloablly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, brute-force, rate-limiting

I am using express-rate-limit@2.11.0 module and it working fine but it's block the api globally not for the specific api from it's getting hits.

**My Code:**

```
const limiter = new RateLimit({
        windowMs: 15*60*1000,
        max: 100,
        delayMs: 0,
        message: '==> You have made too many attempts in a short period of time, please try later',
        handler: (req, res) => {
            res.format({
                json: () => {
                    res.status(429).json({
                        message: 'You have made too many attempts in a short period of time, please try later'
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        onLimitReached: (req, res, options) => {
            logger.error(options.message, resolveLogger({
                reqURL: req.url,
                statusCode: options.statusCode
            }));
        }
    });
```

Can some suggest me how can I restrict it for ip specific only

Comment: I'd recommend doing it in Apache/Nginx instead. See: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, it is better to limit rates on reverse-proxy, load balancer or any other entry point to your node.js app

If that is not an option for your app, I'd suggest [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible)

```
const { RateLimiterMemory } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');

const opts = {
  points: 100, // 100 points
  duration: 15*60, // Per 15 minutes
};

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(opts);

const rateLimiterMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const isIpLimited = isIpLimited(req.ip);
  if (isIpLimited) {
    // Consume 1 point for each request
    rateLimiter.consume(req.ip)
      .then(() => {
        // There was enough remaining points
        next();
      })
      .catch((rejRes) => {
        // All points consumed
        const secs = Math.round(rejRes.msBeforeNext / 1000) || 1;
        res.set('Retry-After', String(secs));
        res.status(429).send('Too Many Requests');
      });
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(rateLimiterMiddleware);
```

Note: Memory limiter works in current process memory. There are Cluster, Redis and Mongo limiters too, which share state.